# Can a SHA1 key be shared between two different Firebase projects after deleting the connected Firebase app

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, sha1

I created a firebase project for my newly released unity game. The analytics dashboard did not show anything so I thought there is some error.

So I deleted my app(firebase app) from the firebase project. But before deleting the app, I had removed the SHA1 fingerprint from the app. But with some research, I found that it may take 24-48 hours for firebase to start analytics, so may be there was no error, but i deleted it.

Also, there is a way to restore the firebase project, but not an app inside the project. Now can I create another firebase project or another app to receive the analytics data for the same game that I have published ?

Comment: you deleted firebase project or app inside firebase project ??

Comment: I deleted the app inside the project. But before deleting it, i had removed the SHA1 fingerprint